# Android: 10inch android emulator is very slow

Tags: android, performance, gpu

How to increase the 10inch emulator like the nexus 10? I tried to enter some text on my application when logging in to the facebook, each character appear almost 10 second after i typed. The other device emulator is ok e.g. 7inch.

Does any know how to increase the speed. I have checked Host GPU option.

Comment: Do you need an actual emulator or would something like [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) do too? The latter is blazing fast - on a reasonably machine even faster than physical devices.

Comment: I have read the other post ... telling to install IntelHAXM.exe and enable the intel visualization thing in the BIOS during restart... I am trying now and see...